# Is our Beta label being removed?

Tags: discussion

Since we learned that [Matter Modeling is graduating](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/5) and [Quantum Computing is graduating](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293) and [Freelancing is graduating](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/25010) and [Retrocomputing is graduating](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/18437) and [Economics is graduating](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2161/20029), I'm curious if Earth Science will be too?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Earth Science will be graduating too.

See [this blog post from 2021-12-16](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/) announcing how Earth Science is graduating along with many other sites.

Comment: Wow this is great news, thanks! I hope Astronomy will graduate too.

Comment: yay! great news.

Comment: @gerrit When we graduate, I will loose my edit with no approve privilege? How much points I will need to recover that privilege if so?

Comment: @Universal_learner No, we will retain beta level thresholds for privileges.  You will not lose any privileges.  There should be an announcement with details some time in December.